# Objective-C Check for Unallowed Characters in String

Tags: objective-c, string

How would I, in objective-c, make it so only strings with a-z characters were allowed? I.E. no & characters, no - characters, etc.

Thanks!
Christian Stewart

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`NSCharacterSet`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s are going to be the key here. First you'll need the character set of alphabetical characters:

```
NSCharacterSet* letters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange('a', 26)];
```

And then, if you want to check if the string contains a character that's not a letter, you can use this set's inverse:

```
NSCharacterSet* notLetters = [letters invertedSet];
```

Then use `NSString`'s [`rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfCharacterFromSet:) with `notLetters`, and if the range doesn't start with `NSNotFound`, there are forbidden characters in your string.

```
NSRange badCharacterRange = [myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notLetters];
if (badCharacterRange.location != NSNotFound) // found bad characters
```

Comment: Arr; beat me while I was typing.