# NSRange How to look for a space OR a return?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsrange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find and replace symbols in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154119/how-to-find-and-replace-symbols-in-a-string)

Sorry if the following is really obvious, but I'm just starting to work with NSRange and found the docs not really helpful with my question.

I have a string and I would like to look through it, starting from the very end. I would like to determine the range from the end of the string to either (1) the first space OR (2) the first return.

This is what I have so far:

```
 NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
```

but how do I tell objective-C something like `rangeOfString:@" " or @"/n"`?

Thanks for any help or suggestions with this!

Comment: Other possibilities with similar answers include: [Replace multiple characters in a string in Cbjective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713918/) and [Check for unallowed characters in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605918/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
NSRange rangeSpace = [myString rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSRange rangeReturn = [myString rangeOfString:@"/n" options:NSBackwardsSearch];

    if(rangeSpace.location < rangeReturn.location)
        //use rangeReturn
    else
        //use rangeSpace
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [rangeOfCharactersInSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfCharacterFromSet%3a)
This sounds like what you're looking for:

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToFind = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSRange charsRange = [testString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charsToFind options:NSBackwardsSearch]
```